# How do I delete activities?

Tags: delete

How do I delete an activity that I have created and assigned to myself?
I cannot see a button that says delete, only an edit button?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a link on the "Activities" tab marked "Delete" for each activity listed.  See screenshot:

[image]

If you do NOT see this button, it's most likely that you don't have the "Delete Activities" permission.  Please speak to whomever manages permissions for your CiviCRM installation.